# How do I setup an "if object exists" condition?

Tags: javascript, object

Is there some way to check if an object exists?  I keep getting an "object required" error.  I know the object does not exist and I would like to bypass a part of my code should that be the case. I don't know what I have not tried...

```
    var codeName = document.getElementById('testCode');
    //I have tried
    if(codeName != null)
    if(codeName.length != 0)
    if(typeOf codeName != 'undefined')
    if(!codeName)
    if(codeName.value != null)
```

Is there any way to see if an object exists?

Comment: Assuming this is JavaScript code, I don't see how C# or ASP.NET MVC are relevant... it's just script running in a page, right?

Comment: Can we see your mark-up to see if your elements with those ID's actually exist?

Comment: `if (typeOf(codeName) == 'object') { }` ?

Comment: On what line are you getting the object required error? It might be on the `document.getElementById('codeList').value.split(",");` part - split that up into lines and check after each line.

Comment: It might help to highlight the line/object that raises the error, otherwise wild stabbing will continue… Also: if(!codeName) should be if(codeName).

Comment: @Bjoern - Thanks. I realize that. I may have put too much information up. See edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the `getElementById` call, `codeName` is either a DOM Element or null. You can use an alert to see which:

```
alert(codeName);
```

So `if (codename != null)` should work.

Does the error happen before it gets that far? I would try adding alerts to see the values as the code runs. Or step through this code in a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var codeName = document.getElementById(code[i]) || null;
if (codeName) {/* action when codeName != null */}
```

if you want to be sure codeName is an Object:

```
if (codeName && codeName instanceof Object) {
  /* action when codeName != null and Object */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var codeList = document.getElementById('codeList');
if(!codeList && !codeList.value && !codeList.value.length) return;
var code = codeList.value.split(","),
    itemCount = code.length;
if(!itemCount) return;
for (var i=0, i<itemCount; i++) {
    var codeName = document.getElementById(code[i]);
    if(!codename || !codename.length) continue;
    //do something here...
}
```

I got a working example here: http://jsbin.com/uduxe4/15

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what `document` is, but you could try something like

```
if(document.getElementById('code'+[i]) == null)
{
//...do Something
}
```

so testing if it exists *before* you using it...

Answer (score -1):

I don't do a whole lot of JS coding, but it seems like your [i] is the problem. As far as I know, [] is used for accessing a field of an array, and you don't have an array. Just use "code" + i

Comment: I thought this too, but apparently [i] is valid in Javscript. Learn something new everyday!

Answer (score -1):

In ruby `nil` is equivalent to `false`.

So try to check just:

`if codeName`

Comment: But this isn't Ruby. (Also, I wouldn't say `nil` is equivalent to `false` in Ruby.)

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id='code1'></div>

var itemCount = 10;
var len = 10;
len = itemCount;
for (var i=0;i<len; i++) {
    var codeName = document.getElementById('code'+ i);
    if(codeName == null)
       alert("Nope " + i);
    else
        alert("Yep " + i);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Would a try/catch work for you? **[Example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/v4MAg/)**

```
function toDoStuff(elem) {
    codeName = document.getElementById(elem);
    if (!codeName) throw "Object isn't here yet!"
}


for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    try {
        toDoStuff('someElem');
    } catch (err) {
        if (err == "Object isn't here yet!") {
            alert("Object isn't ready yet leaving loop!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work; getElementById doesn't throw an exception when the element isn't found.

Comment: ahh, crap. You're correct, just realized that the [i] does it. Thanks for the down vote!

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try checking that your object inherits from the type your function needs? Like this:

`if(codeName is String)`