# Check if [i] exists or not

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a script where I want a part to run if `i` exists (meaning that there is a value of `i`, any value) or another part to run if there is no value for `i`, can anyone enlight me?

I am talking about the for loop, something like

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if (var i == doesnt exist) {
        code1 runs
    }
    else {
        code2 runs
    }
}
```

Heres the code in the HTML

```
<script>
function funfacts(o){
    var facts = document.getElementById('funfacts');
    var data = o.query.results.a;
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        var out = document.createElement('a');
        facts.appendChild(out);
        out.href = data[i].href;
        out.innerHTML = data[i].alt;
        out.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: what should be in `data[i]` ? It will exist since you are looping in existing elements. Do you want to know if it is null ?

Comment: Yes i do, i need to know if it is null or doesnt exist before proceeding with the rest of the code

Comment: it can't **not** exist, since it is an element of the data array/object. You need to tell us what to expect in the data to see how to test about their existence.

Comment: Just added the script, it works with YQL query results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
  if(data[i]){
    code1 runs
  } else {
    code2 runs
  }
}
```

This assumes that you are iterating though an array and some of the objects in that array are `null`.  Otherwise, this loop will never run past the last array index, so there is no need to safe guard it unless you actually have `null` in the array.

Note that this also will fail on a zero, since a zero is considered as false in javascript.  If this is a problem in your case, you can compare it with `null`

```
if (data[i] !== null) {
```

And outside a loop you can check to see if an array has a value at an index at all via:

```
if (typeof(data[i]) === 'undefined') {
```

This will see if there is a value at that index, could be false, zero, null or anything else and this test would pass.

But again, inside that loop it's guaranteed to be within the array bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
   if(var i == doesnt exist){
      code1 runs    // this will never be executed
   }
   else{
      code2 runs
   }
}  // I don't see this brace in your code, so I assume it's here
```

is equivalent to:

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    code2 runs
}
```

Perhaps you meant this:

```
if(data.length == 0) {
   code2 runs
}
else {
   for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      code 1 runs
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(var i != null)
```

should do the job for you

You may also want to have a look at [How do I setup an "if object exists" condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399304/how-do-i-setup-an-if-object-exists-condition/4399352#4399352)

Comment: Doesnt work, and i have read the link but still cant make it to work.

Answer (score 0):

How can `i` not exist if you just created it a line before?

You can check if it is set to `undefined` within the loop by:

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
   if (i) {
      //code1 runs
   }
   else{
     //code2 runs
   }
}
```